# how to get IP address of server/localhost using c or c++ programming?

Tags: c++, c

how to get IP address of server/localhost using c or c++ programming? suppose my executable program running on server 198.25.67.25,If I want to identify the IP address "198.25.67.25" .how can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/ipaddr.html)

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/hostname-to-ip-address-c-sockets-linux/ This link may be help u